# Getting "unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Permission denied"

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, dconf

I use GNU/Linux Mint 18.2 (based on Ubuntu 16.04). Very recently, I've started seeing the following error message, repeated many times, when I start some GUI apps (e.g. meld):

```
unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
```

Now, I'm able to work around this by manually changing the ownership of `/run/user/1000/dconf/user`, but that's kind of a lame hack and certainly not robust.

Why have I been seeing this error and what's the "right way" to avoid it (if any)?

Comment: I think it's caused by running certain GUI programs as superser:
I get this same problem when running ktsu to open a terminal app (called terminator) as a root window.  Apparently terminator is using  my  UID instead of root's in /run/user/UID/user, and that can change the owner of the file to root causing "permission denied" when I run terminator as myself.

Answer (score 4):

chown 1000:1000 /run/user/1000/dconf/user

Comment: But will this not revert to the incorrect permissions later? e.g. by being recreated?

Answer (score 4):

The issue can be caused by running a GUI after changing user using `su` command. Certain environmental variables are not changed causing the error. See

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=753882

Try running the program by logging in as that user directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# rmdconfuser - remove dconf user

if [ -e "/run/user/1000/dconf/user" ] 
then
    rm -f /run/user/1000/dconf/user
fi

# Uncomment the next line if mate-settings-daemon is eating up too much memory
# killall -9 mate-settings-daemon
```

then execute `chmod +x rmdconfuser` and place `rmdconfuser` into your `~/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin` as root and `sudo rmdconfuser` to stop the problem. You can also make rmdconfuser set its own uid to root, so you can run it without being root yourself.

Unfortunatelly this is only a work around. The problem may appear again & again.

Comment: Interesting user name you have there. Why would I have the mate-settings-daemon running, though?

Comment: sorry - because it caused the problem of eating the ram on my machine running mate on mint. If you have no mate then simply forget the last line.